# Moving OpenGL model towards 1 direction only

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl, 3d

I have a fixed camera at 0,0,0 on my OpenGL scene and have a model.
The model is translated and rotated, and would like to move it on the right of my camera. However if I translate to x, it will translate towards x of the model and not of the camera.
How can I overcome this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the order in which `glRotate` and `glTranslate` are called. First rotating and then translating will look like you move the camera around. First translating and then rotating looks like you're looking at a table that spins around its axis with your model on top.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my order is correct. Basically I first translate and then rotate. Here I am in a function that captures mouse event, and I would like to shift the model to the right if the mouse is going to the right. How could I do that ? thanks !

Comment: You need to keep some instance variable around that keeps track of how much the model is moved to the right, say `GLdouble offsetX`. Now whenever your mouse moves to the right, increase the `offsetX`, or decrease if it goes to the left. If you're not animating continuously you also need to trigger a redraw when the mouse moved. In your drawing function, add the `offsetX` to the translation command: `glTranslated(offsetX, ...)`.

Comment: That's what I have actually, however when I increase offsetX, the model is moving along its own X axis, and not the camera's one... Anything I am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: That's actually quite strange, maybe my imagination fails me. Anyway, you could compensate for the rotation by hand when translating. Instead of using `offsetX` for the X coordinate, use `glTranslated(offsetX*cos(rotrad), 0, offsetX*sin(rotrad) + <distance you already have>);`, where `rotrad` is the rotation of the model in radians, which you get from degrees by `rotrad = rotdeg / 180.0 * M_PI`. You might have to swap sine and cosine for it to work, and maybe make it `-rotrad` instead of `rotrad`.

Comment: Any time :). I've got to look into this, my imagination's ego is hurt ^^